# NSTimer hangs program after firing

Tags: swift, nstimer

I am creating a timer inside my ViewController.  After it fires once, the program ceases to respond to any further UI events.

I create the timer inside of `ViewDidLoad()` with:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "initTimerFired", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

with timer function (defined as method of ViewController):

```
func initTimerFired(){

    println("Timer fired")
}
```

It successfully fires, but thereafter the program hangs and does not respond to UI events.  If I set `repeat = true` then it runs a couple of times before quitting with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I have looked at many different answers and examples, and I can't see what I am doing wrong.

I am running this on an iOS simulator, using xcode 6.1.

Here is an update.  Thanks to the suggestions and code provided in the first answer, I have something working.  However, my code, which looks to me to be the same, does not work.  In order to implement things within the context of a larger project, I want to know how to avoid the errors I am seeing.  For instance, this works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var strConsole: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        initTaskManager()

    }

    func initTaskManager(){
        let taskManager = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "updateTask", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func updateTask(){

        self.strConsole.text = "\(strConsole.text!)Abc"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

But this version does not.  Only the function names have changed!:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var strConsole: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        initTimer()

    }

    func initTimer(){
        let timer1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "initTimerFired", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func initTimerFired(){

        self.strConsole.text = "\(strConsole.text!)Abc"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

Comment: The example program you linked to Leonardo below works as expected for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use: initTimerFired, change to something else like: handleTimer,

init as a prefix of the function name may confuse Xcode

See here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html

Comment: That is great information!  I would not have guessed that.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do like this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var strConsole: UILabel!

    func startTaskManager(){

        let taskManager = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateTask", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    func updateTask(){

        self.strConsole.text = "\(strConsole.text!)Abc"
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        startTaskManager()

     }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


}
```

Comment: I still get the same result with this.

Comment: I did this exactly, and I still have the same problem.  I'm thinking there is something wrong with my development environment or compiler settings.  Rebooting.

Comment: delete DerivedData folder

Comment: Yours works!  My exact same code does not.  This is annoying.